# Add-Content With Condition On One Line

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get all of this to be on one line, but everything I try doesn't work.  I tried `b but that doesn't backspace you to the line above.  I tried putting the condition inline with the first Add-Content, but that didn't work either.

```
Add-Content $txtpath "p: $strPhone x $strXTEN  |  "
if ($strMobile -ne $null) { Add-Content $txtpath "`m: strMobile  |  " }
Add-Content $txtpath "$strFax"
```

Comment: Don't write a line of text to a file before you finished constructing that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use multiple Add-Content calls because each one will append a newline.  I logged a suggestion a long time ago for a `NoNewline` parameter on Add-Content.  You can vote for it [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/524739/need-nonewline-parameter-on-out-file-add-content-and-set-content).

You can use a StringBuilder for this and then output its contents via Add-Content or Set-Content:

```
$sb = new system.text.stringbuilder
[void]$sb.Append("p: $strPhone x $strXTEN  |  ")
if ($strMobile -ne $null) { [void]$sb.Append("`m: strMobile  |  ") }
[void]$sb.Append($strFax)
Add-Content $txtPath $sb.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what I *think* you are wanting to do is to use the -f format operator, like so:

```
$text =  "p: $strPhone x $strXTEN {0}" -f $( if ($strMobile) {"| m: $strMobile"})   
Add-Content $txtpath $text
```

Comment: How can I add $strFax after the -f on the same line?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Microsoft listened and added the `-NoNewLine` Parameter to Add-Content back in 2015:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/the-powershell-5-nonewline-parameter/